# Pass parameters to parent with parameter list

Tags: c++, parameters, overloading

Consider we have two classes:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    Base(char c) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    Base(double d) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    ~Base() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
};
class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    Derived(int i, float f, char c):Base(c) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    Derived(int i, float f, double d):Base(d) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    ~Derived() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
};
```

This is straightforward and easy to understand. Now, we want to implement a new class DerivedWithParams:

```
class DerivedWithParams : public Base{
public:
    struct Params {
        int i;
        int f;
        char c;
        double d;
    };
    DerivedWithParams(Params* params):Base(params->c) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    DerivedWithParams(Params* params):Base(params->d) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
    ~DerivedWithParams() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
    }
};
```

However, when compiled, it complains:
cannot be overloaded

It seems C++ doesn't support overload with init parameter list. Any workaround for this?

Comment: c++ does support overloading, but you need to change the signature. Your two constructors have the same signature.

Comment: You have twice `DerivedWithParams(Params* params)`...

Comment: @tobi303 by signature - this includes cv-qualifiers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore right, misclicked on delete instea of edit...

Comment: Did you want `struct Params {
        int i;
        int f;
        std::variant<char, double> v;
    };` ?

Comment: But you are NOT overloading here - you are trying to redefine the same constructor  `DerivedWithParams(Params* params)`.

Comment: Why are you passing **all** of the parameters if you only need one to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded functions must have different parameter lists or be const/not-const.

```
DerivedWithParams(Params* params):Base(params->c) {
    cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
}
DerivedWithParams(Params* params):Base(params->d) {
    cout << __FUNCTION__ <<":"<<__LINE__ << endl;
}
```

These two declarations however are identical (`DerivedWithParams(Params* params)`) so the compiler would have no way to know which to call.

If you are intended to make some kind of structure that can contain different types of values, you need a way to identify what it actually contains, and just one function with runtime logic, e.g.

```
struct Params
{
    enum Type
    {
        PARAM_I, PARAM_F, PARAM_C, PARAM_D;
    };
    Type type;
    union
    {
        int i;
        int f;
        char c;
        double d;
    };
};

DerivedWithParams::DerivedWithParams(Params* params)
{
    switch(params->type)
    {
    case Params::PARAM_I:
        std::cout << params->i << std::endl;
        break;
    case Params::PARAM_F:
        std::cout << params->f << std::endl;
        break;
    case Params::PARAM_C:
        std::cout << params->c << std::endl;
        break;
    case Params::PARAM_D:
        std::cout << params->d << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Similar functionality for C++17 is provided by `std::variant`, or you could use the Boost C++ library `boost::variant`.

```
typedef std::variant<int, char, double> Params;
DerivedWithParams::DerivedWithParams(const Params &params)
{
    if (auto val = std::get_if<int>(&params))
    {
        std::cout << "int " << *val << std::endl;
    }
    else if (auto val = std::get_if<char>(&params))
    {
        std::cout << "char " << *val << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to init Base(char) or Base(double) here? I understand c++ doesn't support overload by init parameter list.  But here I didn't workout how to pass the char or double to Base constructor.

Comment: You could pass the `Params` / variant to base itself, otherwise no, you just cant, because you can only construct a base once and you must call a specific overload. You would have to make a default constructor and let the derived class set stuff after.  Or if your only interested in dynamic allocation (new/delete) make a factory function that can do it and call the constructor (`new Derived(char)`, `new Derived(int)`, etc.), or I guess placement new, but thats getting complex (look it up). But its all the same idea, the `switch` or `if`, `else if`, etc. or similar must go *somewhere*

Answer (score 0):

It cannot overload DerivedWithParams, because the compiler has no idea which implementation to chose.
If you call it with `DerivedWithParams foo( &myParams );` which one would it chose?
You need to do something to distinguish the two.